# PropertyAnimation vs. NumberAnimation

Tags: qt, animation, qml

The QML code below animates two rectangles. One uses [`PropertyAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-propertyanimation.html), while the other uses [`NumberAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-numberanimation.html). Both rectangles move similarly. I don't see anything different between the two animation types.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle {
        id: r1
        width: 100; height: 100
        color: "red"

        Behavior on x { PropertyAnimation {} }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: r2
        y: 150
        width: 100; height: 100
        color: "blue"

        Behavior on x { NumberAnimation {} }
    }

    // click anywhere to start animation
    MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: r1.x = r2.x = 200 }
}
```

What is the difference between `PropertyAnimation` and `NumberAnimation`; and when should I use one over the other?

Comment: try to animate `color` and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### tl;dr.

[`NumberAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-numberanimation.html) is *derived* from [`PropertyAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-propertyanimation.html), and thus, it makes logical sense for them to exhibit similar behaviour.

> NumberAnimation is a specialized PropertyAnimation that defines an animation to be applied when a numerical value changes.
>   <sub>[(Source)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-numberanimation.html)</sub>

While `NumberAnimation` *specifically* animates numeric values (e.g. `x`, `y`, `width`, `opacity`), `PropertyAnimation` is *generic* and can animate non-numeric ones (e.g. `color`, `size`).

---

Lé longer answer:

#### 1. `PropertyAnimation` can animate non-numeric types. `NumberAnimation` only animates numbers.

`NumericAnimation` can animate numeric properties such as x, y, width, height, opacity. But it can't animate color, [size](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-size.html), or [points](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-rect.html).

Here's an example where the animation types differ in animating the `color` property. The first rectangle transitions from red to green while the second rectangle stays blue. In this case, `PropertyAnimation` should be used over `NumberAnimation`.

```
Rectangle {
    id: r1
    width: 100; height: 100
    color: "red"

    Behavior on color { PropertyAnimation {} }  // works
}

Rectangle {
    id: r2
    y: 150
    width: 100; height: 100
    color: "blue"

    Behavior on color { NumberAnimation {} }  // fails
}

MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: r1.color = r2.color = "green" }
```

But then again, you can [`ColorAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-coloranimation.html) instead...

#### 2. `PropertyAnimation` is generic.

This is a build-off from **#1**. But this is another advantage on its own.

Since `PropertyAnimation` is more generic, it can be used if you decide to have a dynamic [`PropertyAnimation::property`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-propertyanimation.html#property-prop).

Here's an example where the animation property is user-provided:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 100; height: 100
    color: "red"
    PropertyAnimation { id: animation; target: rect }
}

MouseArea { 
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: { 
        animation.property = t1.text;
        animation.to = t2.text;
        animation.start();
    }
}

Row {
    width: parent.width; height: 50
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    TextField { id: t1; width: parent.width/2; height: 50; placeholderText: "property" }
    TextField { id: t2; width: parent.width/2; height: 50; placeholderText: "to" }
}
```

Using `NumberAnimation` also works, but restricts the viable properties to only numeric ones... users can't simulate supernovas or rainbows. :(

#### 3. `NumberAnimation` is strict.

Let's compare the `from` and `to` properties.

- [`NumberAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-numberanimation.html)

  - `from`: `real`
  - `to`: `real`
- [`PropertyAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-propertyanimation.html)

  - `from`: `variant`
  - `to`: `variant`

This makes `NumberAnimation` stricter. QML will prevent you from making silly mistakes:

```
NumberAnimation {
    id: animation
    to: "green"    //  Invalid property assignment: number expected   
}
```

Use it when you're *strictly* limited animating numbers.

This also means that using `NumberAnimation` can improve **readability** and **communication**. It tells the people reading your code that you're only intending to animate numbers — not anchors, colours, unicorns or whatever.

#### 4. `NumberAnimation` is more efficient at animating numbers.

– says Qt:

> Specialized property animation types have more efficient implementations than the PropertyAnimation type.
>   <sub>[(Source)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-animations.html)</sub>

Here, the "*specialized types*" refers to `NumberAnimation`, along with [other types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-animations.html#animation-and-transitions-types) such as `AnchorAnimation` and `ColorAnimation`.

I haven't tried profiling QML to benchmark the differences, but it seems like the rule of thumb for choosing animation types is:

- If you're animating numbers, you should default to `NumberAnimation`.
- `PropertyAnimation` should be a *last resort* (prefer the [other types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-animations.html#animation-and-transitions-types)).